# I can't get Set::sort working on lower levels

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp

In my app, I have the following Models and relationships:

- ActiveMember belongsTo Team
- ActiveMember belongsTo Rank
- ActiveMember hasMany ContactInfo
- ContactInfo belongsTo ContactType

In my controller, I am them doing a contained find as so;

```
$this->Team->contain(array(
    'ActiveMember' => array (
        'fields' => array('id','surname','firstname'), 
        'Rank' => array(
            'fields' => array('id','display','position')) , 
                'ContactInfo' => array (
                    'ContactType',
                    'conditions' => 'contact_type_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)'   
                )
            )
        )
    );
$Teams = $this->Team->find('all', array('conditions' => 'Team.active = 1 AND Team.display_order<99'));
```

This then returns an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Team] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Command
                    [display_order] => 1
                    [active] => 1
                )

            [ActiveMember] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [surname] => Bloggs
                            [firstname] => Joe
                            [rank_id] => 1
                            [team_id] => 3
                            [Rank] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [display] => Commander
                                    [position] => 1
                                )

                            [ContactInfo] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [member_id] => 1
                                            [contact_type_id] => 1
                                            [info] => 1234 5678
                                            [ContactType] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1
                                                    [name] => Home Phone
                                                    [format] => #### ####
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [surname] => Smith
                            [firstname] => Jane
                            [rank_id] => 2
                            [team_id] => 3
                            [Rank] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [display] => Dep Comm
                                    [position] => 10
                                )

                            [ContactInfo] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Team] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Support
                    [display_order] => 2
                    [active] => 1
                )

            [ActiveMember] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 124
                            [surname] => Johnson
                            [firstname] => John
                            [rank_id] => 6
                            [team_id] => 1
                            [Rank] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [display] => Member 
                                    [position] => 50
                                )

                            [ContactInfo] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
```

And then I want to sort the result as per 'ORDER BY Team.display_order, Team.Member.Rank.position, Team.Member.surname, Team.Member.firstname'

Given that I can't do this complex sort in the query without doing adhoc joins, I thought I could use Set::sort, called four times to sort the order.

```
$Teams = Set::sort($Teams,'{n}.ActiveMember.{n}.surname','asc');
$Teams = Set::sort($Teams,'{n}.ActiveMember.{n}.firstname','asc');
$Teams = Set::sort($Teams,'{n}.ActiveMember.{n}.Rank.position','asc');
$Teams = Set::sort($Teams,'{n}.Team.display_order','asc');
```

However, despite the Set path of the first three lines returning correct values if I do a Set::extract, they do not have any effect on the array order (either when called as a group, or as the only sort). The final line works.

Can someone please advise where my mistake is, or another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Did you try to write any code the uses the `order` feature of the containable behavior? [Read this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options)  That may help solve most of your sorting needs.